# Multitenancy Clustered Index Design

Tags: sql-server

I have a multitenancy application and I want a clustered index for the data to support fast range queries.

If I design my clustered index like this:

```
(SystemID, EntityID, IsHidden)
```

`SystemID` is the unique identifier for the multitenancy instance, `EntityID` is an identity for the entity and `IsHidden` is a flag whether this row shows up in results or not. Will SQL Server be able to throw out all data not belonging to the system as well as the hide data efficiently? and does the order in which these columns are specified matter?

If I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SystemID = @pSystemID AND IsHidden = 0
```

I guess what I'm trying to do is effectively partition the table so that all rows belonging to a specific system as well as hidden data is physically grouped close together. That way, it can be easily discarded depending on the query against that data.

Is this good or bad? (I'm leaning towards good, I'm not expecting a lot of inserts to be taking place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it like this instead: `(SystemID, IsHidden, EntityID)`. Having the `IsHidden` column *after* the `EntityID` would make it basically useless since the `EntityID` is already unique. Searching for the criteria you give as example (`WHERE SystemID=@SystemID AND IsHidden=0`) would still have to search the entire range of that tenant, since the rows with `IsHidden=0` are spread out across the entire range. Moving this column *before* `EntityID` allows for much more efficient range scans.

One problem you'll face is that searching for a specific `EntityID` will be by default inefficient (`WHERE EntityID=@EntityID`). You can improve things by adding a non-clustered index on `EntityID` but that will only solve part of the problems. The bulk of the issues will arise from joins with other tables, like a details table that will join on condition:

```
FROM Master JOIN Detail ON Master.EntityID = Detail.ParentEntityID
```

As these queries get more complex and the range of candidate rows increases, the efficiency of the non-clustered indexes on the `EntityID`/`ParentEntityID` keys starts to decrease, until they hit [the tipping point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx) and are basically ignored. If possible, make sure **all** these joins specify the clustered index key instead:

```
FROM Master JOIN Detail 
   ON Master.SystemID = Detail.SystemID 
   AND Master.IsHidden = Detail.IsHidden 
   AND Master.EntityID = Detail.ParentEntityID
```

The problem will be that most modeling tools (like EF or Linq) will tend to join by the logical primary key (the `EntityID`) as opposed to the physical clustered key.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the order of the key columns mattered, I sort of expected it to be that way but had to ask. Thanks a bunch for the help!